# Can't select DB on MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm asking this question because I couldn't find the answers.

I am using PHP 7.2 on XAMPP and 1.5.2 MongoDB Driver.

I created performanceWeb DB on my MongoDB server as you can see below:

[image]

Since I was getting an error while querying, I tried a simple code and it's not getting the DB (and therefore the collection):

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");     
    // select a collection

    if ($m == NULL){
        echo "m is NULL</br>";
    }

    if ($m->performanceWeb == NULL){
        echo "DB is NULL</br>";
    }

    if ($m->performanceWeb->usuarios == NULL){
        echo "collection NULL</br>";
    }
```

As you can see the result:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong? Can you see the mistake?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect to mongo as Client, You connecting as Manager.

Please try following codes.

```
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");     
// select a collection

if ($m == NULL){
    echo "m is NULL</br>";
}

if ($m->performanceWeb == NULL){
    echo "DB is NULL</br>";
}

if ($m->performanceWeb->usuarios == NULL){
    echo "collection NULL</br>";
}
```

Comment: I get the error that Client does not exist, I looked for it on http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php and it's not there. Do I have to install another driver? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, MongoClient class is of other php-mongo driver and it is deprecated. I tinks your problem on Manager connection. You should set some parameter on connection. Check following official documentation; http://php.net/manual/tr/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php

Comment: I tried everything but I still get the error. 

Could it be a MongoDB driver installation problem? I coppied php_mongodb.dll to /ext and added it to php.ini, is that enough?

Comment: mongodb appears on phpinfo()

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I couldn't find the Client because it wasn't on Driver Class, it was simply MongoDB/Client. So i just replaced it with "$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->performanceWeb->usuarios;". Thank you very much!